# Get columns from two tables in DatagridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I have two tables and I want to add columns in my `DatagridView` (Data1)

```
mycon.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ItemName,Price1 FROM Pharmacy_Items", mycon);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Data1.Rows.Add();
    Data1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value = reader["ItemName"].ToString();
    Data1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value = reader["Price1"].ToString();
    x++;
}
mycon.Close();
```

Now I want to add a column from another table to my DatagridView (`Data1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value`). How can I achieve this?

I am new to SQL. :)

Comment: what is your other table? you can `Join` it in the first query

Comment: where is another table ? have same records ?!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query, JOIN with table you need and add new column you want to display. The example is below.

```
mycon.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.ItemName, p.Price1, o.ColumnFromOtherTable FROM Pharmacy_Items p INNER JOIN OtherTable o ON p.ID = o.ID", mycon);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Data1.Rows.Add();
    Data1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value = reader["ItemName"].ToString();
    Data1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value = reader["Price1"].ToString();
    Data1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value = reader["ColumnFromOtherTable"].ToString();
    x++;
}
mycon.Close();
```